# Unable to start sonarqube on docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sonarqube

I have an EC2 which is using Amazon Linux 2023 and have installed docker and docker-compose:

- Docker version 20.10.25, build b82b9f3
- Docker Compose version v2.21.0

Using this docker-compose.yml, I am trying to quickly launch sonarqube using `docker-compose up -d`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:community
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      SONAR_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME: sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD: sonar
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: sonar
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sonar
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  sonarqube_logs:
  postgresql:
  postgresql_data:
```

However after a short time after starting, the sonarqube container stops and these are the log entries:

```
2023.09.14 06:29:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2023.09.14 06:29:15 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:42805]
2023.09.14 06:29:15 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[ELASTICSEARCH] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java -Xms4m -Xmx64m -XX:+UseSerialGC -Dcli.name=server -Dcli.script=./bin/elasticsearch -Dcli.libs=lib/tools/server-cli -Des.path.home=/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=/opt/sonarqube/temp/conf/es -Des.distribution.type=tar -cp /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/lib/*:/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/lib/cli-launcher/* org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher
2023.09.14 06:29:15 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
```

Somehow there is no indication of errors?
Anyone experience the same?

Answer (score 1):

The container exited with code 137 and it seems from other replies it is related to memory.

Upon checking the minimum requirements https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/requirements/prerequisites-and-overview/. it seems the min RAM is 2 + 1 = 3GB.

The EC2 was t2.micro which had only 1GB of RAM :(. After upgrading to t2.medium (4GB RAM) it had worked.

Hope this helps!